# Ibus incompatible with Tor Browser in 13.10

Tags: firefox, ibus, tor

I have recently updated to 13.10 from 13.04 and noticed a compatibility issue between the new Ibus and the Tor Browser.

Basically, the Tor Browser does not accept any keyboard inputs, while all other programs do. I tested this with the 64 bit versions 2.3.25-11 and 2.3.25-13 and the 32 bit version 2.3.25-13.

According to this thread, quitting ibus "fixes" the problem:

https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/9353

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 10):

Type this in a terminal:

```
ibus exit
```

Such a simple answer took forever to find. :)

Comment: ibus exit works indeed, thank you. However, every time I change the keyboard layout, it comes up again and I have to repeat it.

Comment: @Bob - Please edit your other answer! Use the contact us link at the bottom of this page to ask for your unregistered account and your new registered account to be merged. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found this fix:

1 - gedit /path/to/start-tor-browser

2 - Add the following line on the second line (immediately after the line containing shebang interpreter directive - #!/bin/sh):

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"
```

> The above line change the default value (ibus - Intelligent Input Bus,
>   an input method framework for multilingual input) for GTK_IM_MODULE
>   environment variable (which specifies an input method module to use)
>   to xim (X Input Method).

3 - Save and close the file

4 - Run the tor script in terminal

```
sh /path/to/start-tor-browser
```

Worked for me using the 64bit version of Tor-Browser, this issue doe not affect the 32bit.

[BUG](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/9353)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I'm unable to comment on the above answer, but I just wanted to point out that this is a known bug and is recorded here along with various work arounds:

https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/9353

Personally, I just went to Language Support and changed my 'Keyboard input method system' to none.