# Tor Browser Bundle not running

Tags: tor

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10. I have installed Vidalia and Tor Browser but when I click on vidalia nothing happens.No Icon in the tray nor any Firefox pop up.

However, vidalia appears to be running (shown in the **System Monitor**).

I have downloaded Tor Browser Bundle and extracted it then ran the `start-tor-browser` file but nothing happens. What am I missing?

[YouTube video of my problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ut3C7MKUhDE).

Comment: Tor Browser Bundle is not compatible with Ubuntu 13.10 without uninstalling ibus first: [Ibus incompatible with Tor Browser in 13.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/361238/ibus-incompatible-with-tor-browser-in-13-10)

Answer (score 0):

[Instructions](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en)

Find out the name of your distribution 

A quick command to run is `lsb_release -c` or `cat /etc/debian_version`. Here's a quick mapping:

```
Debian unstable (sid) is "sid"
Debian 7.0 (wheezy) is "wheezy"
Debian 6.0 (squeeze) is "squeeze"
Ubuntu 13.04 is "raring"
Ubuntu 12.10 is "quantal"
Ubuntu 12.04 is "precise"
Ubuntu 11.10 is "oneiric"
Ubuntu 11.04 is "natty"
Ubuntu 10.04 or Trisquel 4.0 is "lucid"
```

Then to add this line

`deb     http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org <DISTRIBUTION> main`

to the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

by runing this command `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

#### note:

where you put the codename of your distribution (i.e. lenny, sid, maverick or whatever it is) in place of `<DISTRIBUTION>`.

Then add the gpg key used to sign the packages by running the following commands at your command prompt:

```
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 886DDD89
gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Now refresh your sources, running the following command (as root) at your command prompt:

```
apt-get update<br>
```

If there are no errors you're good to continue. 

To install signing key current

`apt-get install deb.torproject.org-keyring`

finally install Tor just run:

```
apt-get install tor
```

Hopefully it will help you.

Comment: I'm a newbie please explain me in simple language.

Comment: I have updated my answer look at that now

Comment: but i got syntax error http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lC2FlIxlm3M&feature=c4-overview&list=UUdhDnTTgEjYspnnBMzyQznw

Comment: you put the version name without `<>` it would be `deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org saucy main`